# Setting a label's text value by multiplying a two different texbox values

Tags: c++, qt, textbox, qt-creator, qlabel

I'm pretty new to Qt and I'm struggling to set a label's text value set to the result of multiplying two other textbox values. 
The user will enter a  number into a textbox and then will press OK. I want the my label to show the result of the entered number * another label.

**Simple Pseudo Code**

```
labelTotal.text = Textboxdistance.text * labelForcePerStep.text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes:

- `QTextEdit::text()` returns content of the text box as a string.
- `QString::toInt()` converts a string to its corresponding integer.
- `QString::number()` converts an integer to its representing string.

Code:

```
int n1 = Textboxdistance.text().toInt();
int n2 = labelForcePerStep.text().toInt();
labelTotal.setText(QString::number(n1 * n2));
```

Comment: Thank you Frogatto:) The only issue I'm having with it is that the textbox I'm trying to access is on a different form. Would you know how to access it?

Comment: @Joe In Qt we don't have anything called "form". We only have dialogs and main windows. Apart from this matter, there are several ways to pass data between dialogs or windows: signal/slot, interface methods, public properties, etc. Due to keeping this thread single-focused on a single problem, you're encouraged to post your question as a separate question. However, be aware that first search your questions in Google, if you couldn't find proper answers, consider asking them in SO, since a _lot_ of duplicate questions are getting injected to the SO daily which isn't good at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information! I'll search it up on Google:) Thanks a lot for your time Frogatto!